Pandas Setting with Copy Warning on different csv files
I'm running this script that parses through a CSV, navigates to each URL in that CSV, parses for an author, and then writes it to that CSV using Pandas. However, it keeps throwing this error:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_filtered['author'] = authors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrewchung/Documents/24-25/SIPA + Wayback/GothamDispatch/src/AuthorTextScraperv2.py", line 109, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

And then throws this error:
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8, saw 8

It works for only a few of the CSV files that I parse but always fails at different ones. The relevant code is below:
# Iterate through each file in the input path
for filename in os.listdir(input_path):
    file_path = os.path.join(input_path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

        # Ensure 'date' column is in datetime format and naive
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.tz_localize(None)

        # Ensure last_month is naive
        last_month = last_month.replace(tzinfo=None)

        # Filter rows for the last month
        df_filtered = df[df['date'] >= last_month]

        articles = df_filtered['url'].tolist()
        authors = []
        for url in articles:
            print(f"Getting data from {url}")
            headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14.5; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0"}
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                content = response.text
            else:
                print(f"Failed to fetch article from {url}")
                authors.append("none")
                continue

            soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
            author = get_author(soup)
            print(f"Author: {author}")
            authors.append(author)

        df_filtered['author'] = authors

        # Save the filtered DataFrame to the output directory
        output_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, filename)
        df_filtered.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)


Again, I would have to ask why you are dragging pandas in to what is a very simple text manipulation problem.  What does pandas bring to the party?  cvs files are very easy to read and write, and then you would have full control, with no mysteries in the background.

OP: Just do df_filtered = df[df['date'] >= last_month].copy() and you'll get rid of the Warning. Although the error you provided is pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8, saw 8 meaning that the CSV file is not properly formatted.

@TimRoberts I do think that this is a valid use case for pandas. Sample code shows date-manipulation and filter, column extraction, and appending new columns.

@Quang Hoang - it is the statement df_filtered['author'] = authors causing the warning not the one you identify.

@user19077881 that assignment causes the warning, but the one identified gets rid of it.

Thank you to all of your comments! I figured out that one of the several thousand files it was parsing was not a csv but another python file...argh. Thanks for the help!
